# Inspect TCP packets from JVM to Database

Tags: java, tcp

I am using Java program with a database. I am doing in flight encryption feature provided by JDBC driver. Just to be sure, I need to examine the TCP packets going from Java(JVM actually at runtime) to database. How can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: You can use JProfiler but you will not see the TCP packets, instead you will see the executed queries and the opened secession. For TCP packets you can use charlesproxy

Comment: you need to do this from inside your java program or by observing the network from outside? if you are able to observe the network, you can use Wireshark. https://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you need to verify that traffic is encrypted between your application and the database host, you need to do that by examining the packets *after* they leave you app. The JDBC driver is the last layer before data packets enter the networking stack (i.e. OS TCP) and it's the part of your application which performs the encryption, so you can't verify encryption before that.

You can examine network traffic with special tools, such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), as Levan pointed out, or any other packet analyzer/sniffer supported by your OS. On Linux, using [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/):
`tcpdump port 3306 -s 65535 -x -n -q -tttt > packets.out`

As a final note, there are RDMS which can enforce encryption usage at user level, most notably [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html#alter-user-tls): `ALTER USER '...@...' REQUIRE SSL;`